# Resultados incorrectos en calculadora de binario a decimal utilizando la norma IEEE 754

Tags: python, tkinter

Este programa está realizado con Tkinter. Es una calculadora para pasar cadenas de 32 bits en binario a números decimales utilizando la norma IEEE 754.

Había hecho la calculadora sin interfaz gráfica y funcionaba. Pero ahora está teniendo un problema al momento de tomar mi lista de números y procesarla para, posteriormente, insertar el resultado en la pantalla_calculadora.

```
from tkinter import *

#Funciones

#Signo

def signo(sign):

    """Determina el signo del número"""

    if ( sign == 0):
        sign = '+'
    else:
        sign = '-'
    return sign

#EXPONENTE Y MANTISA

def es_cero(x):

    """define si el exponente es 0"""

    cont = 0
    for i in x:
        if (i == 0):
            cont +=1
    if (cont == len(x)):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok

def es_255(exp):

    """define si el exponente es 255"""

    cont = 0
    for i in exp:
        if (i == 1):
            cont +=1
    if (cont == 8):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok

def calculo_exponente(exp):

    """define el numero que reprensenta el exponente"""

    if (es_cero(exp)):
        exp = -126
    elif (es_255(exp)):
        exp = 'NaN'
    else:
        exponente = 0
        j = 7
        for i in exp:
            if (i == 1):
                exponente = exponente + (1*(2**j))
            j = j-1
        exp = exponente - 127
    return exp

def resolucion_del_numero_desnorm(mantisa, exp):

    """resolucion del numero que representa la mantiza elevada al exponente, Desnormalizada"""

    j = -1
    resultado = 0
    for i in mantisa:
        if (i == 1) and (j > -24):
            resultado = resultado + (1*(2**(j+exp)))
        j -=1
    return resultado

def resolucion_del_numero_norm(mantisa, exp):

    """resolucion del numero que representa la mantiza elevada al exponente, Normalizada"""

    mantisa.insert(0, 1)
    j = 0
    resultado = 0
    for i in mantisa:
        if (i == 1) and (j > -24):
            resultado = resultado + (1*(2**(j+exp)))
        j -=1
    return resultado

def resolucion(lista):

    """resolucion del problema completo"""

    #Exponente
    exp = lista[1:9]
    exponente = calculo_exponente(exp)

    #Mantisa
    mantisa = lista[9:32]
    if (exponente == -126):
        if es_cero(mantisa):
            resultado = 0
            return resultado
        else:
            resultado = resolucion_del_numero_desnorm(mantisa, exponente)
            return resultado
    elif (exponente == 'NaN'):
        if es_cero(mantisa):
            resultado = ' infinito '
            return resultado
        else:
            resultado = 'Not a Number.'
            return resultado
    else:
        resultado = resolucion_del_numero_norm(mantisa, exponente)
        return resultado

def solucion():

    """Esta es la funcionalidad del boton igual '=' """

    #Aquí transformo lo que contiene mi pantalla de la calculadora en una lista, para poder manipularla. 
    #Porque mis funciones están diseñadas para operar con listas.
    lista_x = pantalla_calculadora.get()
    lista = list(lista_x)

    sig = signo(lista[0])
    resultado = resolucion(lista)

    if resultado != 'Not a Number.':
            pantalla_calculadora.delete(0, END)
            pantalla_calculadora.insert(0, sig)             #Realmente no se si esta forma de
            pantalla_calculadora.insert(1, resultado)       #mostrar el resultado es la correcta
    else:
        pantalla_calculadora.insert(0, resultado)

def click_boton(valor):

    """Click en el boton"""

    global i
    pantalla_calculadora.insert(i, valor)
    i += 1

def borrar_anterior():

    """Funcionalidad para borrar el ultimo numero agregado"""

    global i
    pantalla_calculadora.delete((len(pantalla_calculadora.get())-1), END)
    i -= 1

def borrar_pantalla():

    """Funcionalidad para borrar toda la pantalla"""

    global i
    pantalla_calculadora.delete(0, END)
    i = 0

#Sector de pantalla y botones

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Calculadora IEEE 754")
ventana.geometry("680x120")

i = 0


#Pantalla de la calculadora

pantalla_calculadora = Entry(ventana, font=("Calibri 24"), width = 41)
pantalla_calculadora.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5, padx= 10, pady = 4)


#Forma y Funcionalidad de botones de la calculadora

boton0 = Button(ventana, text = "0", width = 20, height = 2, command = lambda: click_boton(0))
boton1 = Button(ventana, text = "1", width = 20, height = 2, command = lambda: click_boton(1))

boton_borrar_anterior = Button(ventana, text = "<--", width = 10, height = 2, command = lambda: borrar_anterior())
boton_borrar_pantalla = Button(ventana, text = "C", width = 10, height = 2, command = lambda: borrar_pantalla())

boton_igual = Button(ventana, text = "=", width = 20, height = 2, command = lambda: solucion())


#Agregar botones en pantalla

boton0.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 1, pady = 5)
boton1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 5)

boton_borrar_anterior.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 1, pady = 5)
boton_borrar_pantalla.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 5)

boton_igual.grid(row = 1, column = 4, padx = 1, pady = 5)


#Con mainloop generamos un bucle que permite ver la ventana y va a albergar todo el contenido
ventana.mainloop()
```

A la calculadora se le debe ingresar una serie de 32 números, compuesta por 0 y 1. Ni mas, ni menos.

Los números para probar son los siguientes, pueden copiar y pegar:

- **`10000000000000000000000000000000`**: por pantalla debería salir: `-0`
- **`00000000010000000000000000000000`**: por pantalla debería salir: `+5.877471754111438e-39`
- **`01000000000000000000000000000000`**: por pantalla debería salir: `+2`
- **`01000000000010000000000000000000`**: por pantalla debería salir: `+ 2.125`
- **`11111111111111111111111111111111`**: por pantalla debería salir: `Not a Number`.
- **`01111111100000000000000000000000`**: por pantalla debería salir: `+ Infinito`

Lo que sucede es que siempre, no importa que cadena de bits ingrese, el resultado es: `-5.877471754111438e-39`, que coincide con el caso del número `00000000010000000000000000000000`, pero no debería ser así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la función `solucion`, en concreto en:

```
lista_x = pantalla_calculadora.get()
lista = list(lista_x)
```

`lista_x` es una cadena de caracteres, con `list(lista_x)` consigues una lista de caracteres resultado de descomponer la cadena, pero **`resolucion` espera una lista de enteros**.

El problema se resuelve simplemente con:

```
lista = [int(c) for c in lista_x]
```

o :

```
lista = list(map(int, lista_x))
```

Al pasar una lista de caracteres, por ejemplo, las comparaciones `if (i == 0)` de `es_255` o `es_cero` son siempre falsas ya que `i` será en todo caso `"0"` pero no `0`.

Comment: Que buena información me acabas de dar! No se me había ocurrido que list(lista_x) generaba una lista pero de caracteres! Supuse que iba a ser de enteros, pero claro, pertenecen a una cadena!

Comment: Gracias! Y, por cierto, ya funciona de 10. :D